# Should you use apostrophe s for "No man's land" if it really belongs to no man?

Tags: apostrophe

When talking about "No man's land" if the land belongs to no man, then should you use an apostrophe s?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's someone's land or not, that's how the genitive case is formed. That's the way it is.

Comment: Think of it this way: the possessive modifies the *possessor*, not the *possessee*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask yourself the question: `Whose land is this?` And you would answer with: `No man's` (i.e. for better understanding: `no one's`), meaning that it doesn't belong to any man.